# Why are my images invisible even after adding background image with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to build a game similar to the snake game, except it is with shark and a fish. I have written a program that works exactly like the game I wanted to make, but when I tried using an image instead of background color for shark and fish, the just became invisible. I am quoting the code I have written for this. Please suggest how to change background colors of the thing representing shark and fish to their images. the pictures are in the same folder as the code files.

EDIT: i hosted the images online and they are still not visible....

please pardon if there are any mistakes in my code as i am not very great at programming...

```js
//constants n variables
let inputdir = {x: 0, y: 0};
const eatsound = new Audio('eat.wav');
const gosound = new Audio('gameover.wav');
const movesound = new Audio('move.wav');
const musicsound = new Audio('music.mp3');
let speed = 5;
let score = 0;
let lastPaintTime = 0;
let sharkarr = [
    {x: 13, y: 15}
]
fish = {x: 6, y: 7};


//game functions
function main(ctime) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    //console.log(ctime)
    if((ctime - lastPaintTime)/1000 < 1/speed){
        return;
    }
    lastPaintTime = ctime;
    gameEngine();
}

function isCollide(sharkarr) {
    if(sharkarr[0].x >= 18*2 || sharkarr[0].x <= -18 || sharkarr[0].y >= 18*2 || sharkarr[0].y <= -18){
        return true;
    }
}

function gameEngine(){
    // updating fish, shark
    if(isCollide(sharkarr)){
        gosound.play();
        musicsound.pause();
        inputdir = {x: 0, y: 0};
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert("GAME OVER!");
        }, 2000);
        sharkarr = [{x: 13, y: 15}];
        musicsound.play();
        score = 0;
        scoreBox.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
    }

    //fish eaten = score+ + fish moved
    if(sharkarr[0].y === fish.y && sharkarr[0].x === fish.x){
        eatsound.play();
        score += 1;
        scoreBox.innerHTML = "Score: " + score
        let a = 1;
        let b = 18;
        fish = {x: Math.round(a + (b - a)*Math.random()), y: Math.round(a + (b - a)*Math.random())}
    }

    //moving shark
    for (let i = sharkarr.length - 2; i>=0 ; i--){
        //const element = array[i];
        sharkarr[i+1] = {...sharkarr[i]};
    }

    sharkarr[0].x += inputdir.x;
    sharkarr[0].y += inputdir.y;
    
    // display shark
    board.innerHTML = "";
    sharkarr.forEach((e, index)=>{
        sharkelement = document.createElement('div');
        sharkelement.style.gridRowStart = e.y;
        sharkelement.style.gridColumnStart = e.x;

        if(index === 0){
            sharkelement.classList.add('shark')
        }
        else{
            sharkelement.classList.add('shark');
        }
        board.appendChild(sharkelement);
    })
    // display food
    fishelement = document.createElement('div');
    fishelement.style.gridRowStart = fish.y;
    fishelement.style.gridColumnStart = fish.x;
    fishelement.classList.add('fish');
    board.appendChild(fishelement);
}


//main logic
window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
window.addEventListener('keydown', e =>{
    inputdir = {x: 0, y: 1} //starts the game
    movesound.play();
    musicsound.play();
    switch (e.key) {
        case "ArrowUp":
            //console.log("ArrowUp");
            inputdir.x = 0;
            inputdir.y = -1;
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            //console.log("ArrowDown");
            inputdir.x = 0;
            inputdir.y = 1;
            break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
            //console.log("ArrowLeft");
            inputdir.x = -1;
            inputdir.y = 0;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            //console.log("ArrowRight");
            inputdir.x = 1;
            inputdir.y = 0;
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }
})
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: blue;
}

.body{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#bg{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#title{
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 98%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: medium;
}

#scoreBox{
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 98%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: medium;
}

#board{
    width: 98%;
    height: 85%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    border: 10px solid red;
}

.shark{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url('https://postimg.cc/dDBdCsP4');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fish{
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url('https://postimg.cc/SYNnd9FV');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eat The Fish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <video id="bg" autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="bg.mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="title">EAT THE FISH!!!</div>
        <div id="scoreBox">Score: 0</div>
        <div id="board"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules reveal? Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Amend the URL accordingly. Make sure your background is on a _visible_ element with _positive height and width_.

Comment: The bg.mp4 is not going to work in the stack overflow snippet unless the file is hosted somewhere on the internet and you use the appropriate url for it.  Any chance you can rework this to be a self-contained example of your problem, or is this problem actually related to locating the mp4?

Comment: Dear @Sebastian Simon, I did check it that way but the browser is showing no errors. Just the images are not visible. everything else is fine. please check the .shark and .fish classes in css and suggest how to attach imsges so that they are visible.

Comment: Hello dear Wyck, The problem is actually with making the shark and fish visible, which are part of the game and not actually the background. The background works fine. Please check the .shark and .fish files and suggest how to attach images so that they are visible.

Comment: @AmanJha Have you checked the Network tab in your dev tools? Look for the resource files — the may not be loaded. Have you checked the elements with the `shark` or `fish` class? Is the background image actually applied to them? From your comments, I couldn’t really determine that you checked those things.

Answer (score 1):

`background-clip` is for controlling whether a background image extends beyond its element's boundaries.  It is not for embedding video clips in the background, and does not accept a `url()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Your `background-image` rules should work (provided the path to the images is correct) but they are commented out.

Comment: Actually that was for adding a video to my background and it is working fine... I was asking how to make my shark and fish visible, in place of them I have used background colors for now. But you answer taught me something. The video was working because of the attachment in html code, not the css one. Thank you so much for teaching me that.

Comment: but sir, please check the .shark and .fish classes in css and tell how can I attach images there. background-image:; is not working there, and all the files are in the right place, in the same folder as the html, css and js files.

Comment: Those lines are currently commented out, so will have no effect -- if that's also the case in your real css you'll just need to remove the comment tags (the `/*` and `*/` before and after the rules)

Comment: Sorry sir, I commented them out since they were not working, but they arent working even after incorporating them into the code... thanks for remindinme, I will edit my questiom

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line:

```
background-clip: url(bg.mp4);
```

to

```
background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200);
background-clip: border-box;
```

Read more about [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

I also added some placeholder images to show that your issue is almost certainly a result of an invalid path to your images.

```js
//constants n variables
let inputdir = {x: 0, y: 0};
const eatsound = new Audio('eat.wav');
const gosound = new Audio('gameover.wav');
const movesound = new Audio('move.wav');
const musicsound = new Audio('music.mp3');
let speed = 5;
let score = 0;
let lastPaintTime = 0;
let sharkarr = [
    {x: 13, y: 15}
]
fish = {x: 6, y: 7};


//game functions
function main(ctime) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    //console.log(ctime)
    if((ctime - lastPaintTime)/1000 < 1/speed){
        return;
    }
    lastPaintTime = ctime;
    gameEngine();
}

function isCollide(sharkarr) {
    if(sharkarr[0].x >= 18*2 || sharkarr[0].x <= -18 || sharkarr[0].y >= 18*2 || sharkarr[0].y <= -18){
        return true;
    }
}

function gameEngine(){
    // updating fish, shark
    if(isCollide(sharkarr)){
        gosound.play();
        musicsound.pause();
        inputdir = {x: 0, y: 0};
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert("GAME OVER!");
        }, 2000);
        sharkarr = [{x: 13, y: 15}];
        musicsound.play();
        score = 0;
        scoreBox.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
    }

    //fish eaten = score+ + fish moved
    if(sharkarr[0].y === fish.y && sharkarr[0].x === fish.x){
        eatsound.play();
        score += 1;
        scoreBox.innerHTML = "Score: " + score
        let a = 1;
        let b = 18;
        fish = {x: Math.round(a + (b - a)*Math.random()), y: Math.round(a + (b - a)*Math.random())}
    }

    //moving shark
    for (let i = sharkarr.length - 2; i>=0 ; i--){
        //const element = array[i];
        sharkarr[i+1] = {...sharkarr[i]};
    }

    sharkarr[0].x += inputdir.x;
    sharkarr[0].y += inputdir.y;
    
    // display shark
    board.innerHTML = "";
    sharkarr.forEach((e, index)=>{
        sharkelement = document.createElement('div');
        sharkelement.style.gridRowStart = e.y;
        sharkelement.style.gridColumnStart = e.x;

        if(index === 0){
            sharkelement.classList.add('shark')
        }
        else{
            sharkelement.classList.add('shark');
        }
        board.appendChild(sharkelement);
    })
    // display food
    fishelement = document.createElement('div');
    fishelement.style.gridRowStart = fish.y;
    fishelement.style.gridColumnStart = fish.x;
    fishelement.classList.add('fish');
    board.appendChild(fishelement);
}


//main logic
window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
window.addEventListener('keydown', e =>{
    inputdir = {x: 0, y: 1} //starts the game
    movesound.play();
    musicsound.play();
    switch (e.key) {
        case "ArrowUp":
            //console.log("ArrowUp");
            inputdir.x = 0;
            inputdir.y = -1;
            break;
        case "ArrowDown":
            //console.log("ArrowDown");
            inputdir.x = 0;
            inputdir.y = 1;
            break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
            //console.log("ArrowLeft");
            inputdir.x = -1;
            inputdir.y = 0;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            //console.log("ArrowRight");
            inputdir.x = 1;
            inputdir.y = 0;
            break;
        
        default:
            break;
    }
})
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: blue;
}

.body{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/200);
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#bg{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#title{
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 98%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: medium;
}

#scoreBox{
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 98%;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: medium;
}

#board{
    width: 98%;
    height: 85%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(18, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(18, 1fr);
    border: 10px solid red;
}

.shark{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/30/20');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fish{
    background-color:yellow;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/30/20');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eat The Fish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <video id="bg" autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="bg.mp4">
        </video>
        <div id="title">EAT THE FISH!!!</div>
        <div id="scoreBox">Score: 0</div>
        <div id="board"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, sir, I am asking about the classes .fish and .shark which I used in css. But your answer has resulted in an improvement in my coding skills. Thank you so much. I appreciate you for that, but can you please suggest something for making shark and fish contain images?

Comment: `.fish` and `.shark` do contain images. Did you run the snippet in my answer?

Comment: Yes, sir, the images you added are working, but when I add my images, they just arent visible without any apparent error...

Comment: **Your path is (most likely) not correct to the images.** Edit your question to show your directory structure so we can help you with that.

Comment: I think it is not, because in visual studio code when I type the file name it shows the file. also, all the files i have used are in the same folder as the code files...

Comment: I have hosted the images online sir... please check via the following links.... https://postimg.cc/SYNnd9FV  and https://postimg.cc/dDBdCsP4